# Combo box shows value member instead of Display Member

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `combobox` named `cmbEmployeeNo` and I populate it with a `dataset` in `runtime`.

```
private void populateEmployees()
{
    try
    {
        cmbEmployeeNo.DataSource = objNoPayBLL.getEmployees();
        cmbEmployeeNo.DisplayMember = "NAME_INI";
        cmbEmployeeNo.ValueMember="EMP_NO";
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

But instead of displaying "`NAME_INI`" it always shows "`EMP_NO`" when it is populated.

The `objNoPayBLL.getEmployees()` method provides data correctly.

I have the same `combobox` and the population method in another form and it works fine as expected. But this one does not.

Help me please.

Comment: copy paste from another form

Comment: I did it but no progress.

Comment: double check that the `cmbEmployeeNo.DataSource` has data organized in the way you expect it, by using the data set inspector in the debugger

Comment: Be sure EMP_NO is a property and not a field.

Answer (score 1):

**NAME_INI, your Display Member, needs to be implemented as a getter/setter**

I encountered this same issue and the issue was the DisplayMember on my DataSource class did not have a get method and the ValueMember did. The combo box class expects these not just to be members, but get properties so when it doesn't see DisplayMember's get property, it fails silently and uses ValueMember as a default.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of validation happening in the background with this type of binding, try to set the datasource last and see if it helps

```
cmbEmployeeNo.DisplayMember = "NAME_INI";
cmbEmployeeNo.ValueMember="EMP_NO";
cmbEmployeeNo.DataSource = objNoPayBLL.getEmployees();
```

Comment: That's odd, the ordering should not cause a runtime error - could you post the exception detail?

Comment: It shows  " System.Data.DataRowView " inside the combo box

Comment: So it does not throw an exception? What does objNoPayBLL.getEmployees() return, a DataTable? From the looks of it it seems you are binding to a DataTable and not the DataView, try to bind to the table's .DefaultView property.

Comment: Of course it returns finally a data table >>

public DataTable getEmployees()
    {
            return (objSQL.getDataSet(objSQL.strQueryEmployeeAllo_Prof, "tblEmployees")).Tables["tblEmployees"];
        }

Comment: Try the following:

 cmbEmployeeNo.DataSource = objNoPayBLL.getEmployees();
    cmbEmployeeNo.DisplayMember = "NAME_INI";
 cmbEmployeeNo.ValueMember = "EMP_NO";
 cmbEmployeeNo.DataBind();

Answer (score 0):

I found the error accidently and its totally strange to me.

The oracle query for the data source of the  cmbEmployeeNo combo box *(Here I access it with objNoPayBLL.getEmployees() method)* is as follows.

```
SELECT  A.EMP_NO,UPPER(P.NAME_INI) FROM  EMP_PROFILE P,EMP_ALLOCATION A WHERE A.EMP_NO=P.EMP_NO ORDER BY P.NAME_INI
```

I needed the employee name with initials in upper case and so I used **UPPER(P.NAME_INI)** here.But when I remove the UPPER(P.NAME_INI)  and change it into just **P.NAME_INI** the combo box shows the display member properly.

```
SELECT  A.EMP_NO,P.NAME_INI FROM  EMP_PROFILE P,EMP_ALLOCATION A WHERE A.EMP_NO=P.EMP_NO ORDER BY P.NAME_INI
```

What the hell this oracle capital and simple do with  C# combo box?

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView DisplayMember and Your DB coulmn Name both should match else it will throw Exception.Try To Use Some Alias name for UPPER(P.NAME_INI). I think that will work.